# Ubuntu does not detect any usb port, wifi, ethernet or webcam

Tags: networking, dual-boot, usb, bluetooth, webcam

I have dual booted ubuntu with windows 10. When I first time booted ubuntu everything was working fine.I installed a few packages using dpkg and then I booted up Windows and then again ubuntu. At that point I found out that my computer is completely isolated. It does not detect any form of external device. It doesnot connect to wifi or bluetooth, nor does it detect my webcam.

I tried many solutions given online but none worked. Please help with this.

Thanx

Comment: Have you shutted down your computer with an usb drive put on?

Comment: Is the hybrid shutdown of Win 10 disabled?

Comment: @bitseater Yes my hard disk was still plugged in when I shut down my pc. But no background tasks were running.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find drivers manually for usb, webcam and wifi.

Go to ubuntu setting-->Softwares and Updates--> Then click on..Additional drivers.

It will show lists of drivers, just select relevant drivers, It will start installing.

Comment: Additional drivers tab doesn't show anything.

Comment: Additional Drivers installs Broadcom wireless drivers only. Is that what he has? How can you know?

Comment: c@chili555 I am the one who asked the question. I saw that the additional drivers tab didn't show anything.